# Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema when prepopulating my room

Tags: java, android, database, gradle, android-room

I have a Database (.db) that I want to use to pre-populate my Android Room Database. But even with many tries and researches, I have the same problem.
Here is the error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: countries(com.example.pays.Pays_DB).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='countries', columns={name=Column{name='name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, phonecode=Column{name='phonecode', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, shortname=Column{name='shortname', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='countries', columns={}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

For me, the problem is because my database is empty, but it is not. What is the issue?

Here is my code:

**Pays_DB.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "countries")
    public class Pays_DB {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        public int id;
    
        @NonNull
        public String shortname;
    
        @NonNull
        public String name;
    
        @NonNull
        public int phonecode;
    }
```

**Database.java**

```
@androidx.room.Database(entities = {Pays_DB.class}, version = 2)
public abstract class Database extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract Pays_DAO dao();
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
...
public void DBCreate(){
        if (db == null){
            synchronized (Database.class){
                if (db == null){
                    db = Room.databaseBuilder(this,
                            Database.class, "countries.db")
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .createFromAsset("countries.db")
                            .build();
                    SupportSQLiteDatabase sdb = db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my Database : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LPB07TQaDuwggs_DJ5QIfYdy6H4Ph-_6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Accessing to external links is not something everyone will do. If you want people to pay attention to your question, you should include your schema model to verify whether it matches or not the Pays_DB class.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the table name in the pre-packaged database is named **tbl_country**. Room is expecting to find a table called **countries**.

- *Really (`TableInfo{name='countries', columns={}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}` is saying that it didn't find a matching table at all as a table MUST have at least one column))*

You could use:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "tbl_country")
```

to overcome this issue (you would have to change Pays_DAO accordingly).

**HOWEVER**,
you would then encounter ongoing issues as Room would still not find what it expects as then column names do not match what Room expects.

**That is** Room expects a table to exist in the pre-packaged database according to:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `shortname` TEXT NOT NULL, `name` TEXT NOT NULL, `phonecode` INTEGER NOT NULL)
```

The tbl_country table in your database is defined using :-

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_country (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NOM_PAYS TEXT, NOM_PAYS_SHORT TEXT, POPULATION INTEGER, CAPITALE TEXT)
```

They are worlds apart.

What you need to do is create a table in the pre-packaged database that matches what room expects (at present the first SQL statement above) and populate that with suitable data. The tbl_country would then be ignored as far as room is concerned.

If you want to actually use the tbl_countries then you additionally need to have a class, annotated with @Entity, that defines the columns as per the tbl_countries table.

e.g.

```
@Entity(tableName = "tbl_country")
class Country {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    Long ID=null;
    String NOM_PAYS;
    String NOM_PAYS_SHORT;
    Integer POPULATION;
    String CAPITALE;
}
```

- this isn't the only option, but others would depend upon what you are trying to achieve. You may wish to amend you question to further explain your requirements.

**Note** before rerunning, it would be best to uninstall the App (noting that this deletes the database and thus any data is lost).

**Example Fix (just getting it to run successfully)**

1. In the tool that you are using to create the pre-packaged database run the SQL
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `shortname` TEXT NOT NULL, `name` TEXT NOT NULL, `phonecode` INTEGER NOT NULL);

- Note that this is extracted from the generated Java from the class **Database_Impl** in the method **createAllTables** (i.e. what Room expects (not the room_master_table)).

2. Save the changes and copy the changed pre-packaged database file to replace the asset.

Here's a screen shot that highlights some of the above
[image]

3. Run the App (after uninstalling) and it will run successfully.

- The **countries** table will be empty unless you populated it
- The **tbl_countries** table will exist but not be accessible via room (see part two)

The database via **App Inspection** is:-

[image]
[image]

**Stage Two - accessing tbl_countries**

1. Create the Class **Country** (or whatever class name you deem fit) to be

:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "tbl_country")
class Country {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    Long ID=null;
    String NOM_PAYS;
    String NOM_PAYS_SHORT;
    Integer POPULATION;
    String CAPITALE;
}
```

- Note that Room is quite pernickety so case matters (even though it doesn't to SQLite)
- Note the use of Long (or Integer could be used) for the ID column. If you use long or int (primitives) then Room interprets them as being NotNull (as they cannot be null). **However**, objects can be null and hence their use so as to match what is in the tbl_country table (i.e. `ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` i.e. NOT NULL hasn't been specified). When it comes to integer types for the primary key the rules/interpretations are more convoluted.

2. Amend the class annotated with @Database, namely **Database** to include the Country class (or whatever name you have given the class) in the list of entities in the @Database annotation e.g.

:-

```
@androidx.room.Database(entities = {Pays_DB.class,Country.class}, version = 2)
```

3. Optionally add a Dao to the Pays_DAO class to extract from the tbl_country table e.g.

:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_country")
abstract List<Country> getAllCountry();
```

- note if Pays_DAO is an interface then remove `abstract`

4. To test actually extracting from the tbl_country table (assuming the above) then amend **MainActivity** to include

:-

```
    DBCreate();
    Pays_DAO dao = db.dao();
    for(Country c: dao.getAllCountry()) {
        Log.d("DBINFO","Country is " + c.NOM_PAYS /* etc */);
    }
```

5. Uninstall the App and Run and the log contains

:-

```
D/DBINFO: Country is Canada
D/DBINFO: Country is France
D/DBINFO: Country is Islande
D/DBINFO: Country is Japon
D/DBINFO: Country is Sample
D/DBINFO: Country is Sampl988
```

Comment: @Jadien as you can see I'm creating a example (so will be updating it when I get to add tbl_countries).

Comment: @Jadien P.S. issue was the id column should have been ID and also not long/int but Long/Integer (have corrected the answer accordingly)

Comment: No problem, I'll try that asap

Comment: I still have an error, not exactly the same but near to that
https://mensuel.framapad.org/p/r.158806f6ceeaddcec65c4f10d6741b0a

Comment: @Jadien you are changing the tbl_column `@Entity` looks like you have int not Integer for population. Primitives like int long double  .... will have an implied NOT NULL. Objects such as Integer, Long, Double  don't don't have an implied not null so you MUST use the Object version if you do not have NOT NULL coded in the pre-packaged. The code above works (assuming you haven't changed the pre-packaged database).

Comment: OH! THAT'S WORKING ! I've forgot that I've changed one parameters i'm feeling so stupid xD
Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Jadien that's good. If you feel that the answer helped you then please tick it as answered.